# Changing website name using mod_rewrite and htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rename a folder on my site from http://mywebsite.com/myfolder/ to http://mywebsite.com/mynewfolder/. The urls for the old folder name are all index by Google and may other sites have linked to mine. What is the correct way to ensure that visitors coming to the site on the old folder name will now see the new folder name? Should I chane the name of the folder on my server and then use mod_rewrite to force the new url (folder name)

this seems to work, but is it correct: Redirect 301 /myfolder /mynewfolder
also for SEO would it be better to use: /my-folder-name/

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^oldfolder/ /newfolder/ [R=301,NC]
```

It is widely acknowledged that hyphenating (-) your URLs makes a small impact on SEO as it separates any keywords in your URL rather than having them read as one long string. However saying that I'm pretty sure Google is clever enough to have a go at working this out for themselves. I don't suppose it would hurt and it makes it easier for your user to read at the very least.